# How to remove outside array from joining two separate arrays with collect

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object called `Grade` with two attributes `material` and `strength`.

```
Grade.all.collect { |g| g.material }
#=> [steel, bronze, aluminium]
Grade.all.collect { |g| g.strength }
#=> [75, 22, 45]
```

Now I would like to combine both to get the following output:

```
[steel, 75], [bronze, 22], [aluminium, 45]
```

I currently do this

```
Grade.all.collect{|e| e.material}.zip(Grade.all.collect{|g| g.strength})
#=> [[steel, 75], [bronze, 22], [aluminium, 45]]
```

**Note: I do not want the outside array `[[steel, 75], [bronze, 22], [aluminium, 45]]`**
Any thoughts?

Comment: Tell me, what type does your desired output have?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What do you mean, i want my output to look like this [steel, 75], [bronze, 22], [aluminium, 45]

Answer (score 1):

[Splat](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ruby%20splat&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/&ei=6fZPT5fzHY-f-wb9-8y6Bg&usg=AFQjCNEG6I_H5XxdZM9eJnky7nMyS66XPw&sig2=MWyZWqXgOiVWDh7epiDhBQ) the array to a mere list.

```
*Grade.all.collect{ |g| [g.material, g.strength] }
```